# JS Byte Array to File on PHP Side

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a Uint8Array which have 10000 bytes on Javascript side.

```
var data = new Uint8Array(10000) ;
```

I want to send it to PHP and create a file with it:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'saver.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',  
        data:data,
        processData: false
    });
```

This ajax is sending data (I see it on "Request Payload" section on console) but there is no $_POST record, $_POST array is empty, just silent. How to grab it properly?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known behavior.
For an array of 10000 bytes, you should be able to use

```
$rawPost = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

to get your data from the request instead of checking the $_POST variable.

Note that this method loads the data in-memory, so if the data are too large, you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case.
I get binary file from JS request array : $file['content'] format of Uint8Array.

```
            <?php
            $packed = pack("c*", ...$file['content']);
```